# UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication and application-level credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a SPA (react) which uses ADAL to get a token from AAD, and send that token over to a REST server, which authorizes that token using

```
UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication
```

and everything is great.  But now I need my REST server to make various calls to the Graph API.  My understanding is that normally this is done through the on-behalf-of flow, which makes sense - it allows you to query the graph on behalf of the token user.

HOWEVER, I need my application to query the Graph API under its own set of permissions.  I need this because my application may need to access resources that this token user doesn't have permission to access.  I'm having trouble finding examples of doing this that don't fall back to the on-behalf-of flow.

Do I need to implement a completely separate flow for authentication between my application and AAD?  Do I need to, for example, hit the /authorize and /token endpoints when the app starts up?  My suspicion is that there's an example of how to do this the "correct" way, or perhaps a helper class somewhere, but I can't find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your REST server (or backend API) can make a call to Graph API using Client Credentials Flow, acting like a daemon and using appropriate `Application Permissions`.

When you say "normally this is done through the on-behalf-of flow", that applies when you're trying to call the next API on behalf of users, or using delegated permissions. In your case, as you want to call the Graph API as application itself, you need to make use of Client Credentials Flow.

You can read about Client Credentials Grant [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) depending on whether you are using V1 or V2 endpoint.

**Code Samples**:

[V1 Code Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon)

[V2 Code Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp)